# Trouble installing path for Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python

When I try to enter 'python' into my cmd window, I get back this error:       "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Any ideas how to get my cmd window working?

I tried going into environmental variables and adding my python path to the path system variables, however this is not working.

> python
>   'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you installed python? If so, how?

Comment: Did you reload the cmd window after updating the system PATH? It won't update otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[This might be what you are looking for](https://superuser.com/a/143121)

Running `path` can display the system path, and ensure things are configured correctly :)

Comment: After doing that, I got a huge line of jumbled paths.  Is it supposed to be about 50 files separated by '/'?

Answer (score 0):

Answered over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Assuming you googled and found that (or something similar) yourself, then my guess is you're running into a different issue. For example, the semicolons in the path, especially the proper positioning of them, are very important, could your issue be that simple?

Answer (score 0):

Try entering:

```
py
```

Some systems use this to function like mine. I had the same error but then I tried py and it worked. Maybe this will work for you